# Scala: Future in action

Tags: scala, future

I'm confused about how Scala `Future` works. Can someone explain what's wrong with code:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val numbers = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

def showNumbers() = {
  numbers
}

val futueNumber = future {
  showNumbers.filter((a: Int) => a % 2 == 0)
}

futueNumber onSuccess {
  case resultList => resultList
}

futueNumber
```

I expect to receive a result:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

But REPL outputs:

```
res1: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3644febc
```

Please, give me a short hint, how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you need to await the future for you example to work:

```
val result = Await.result(futureNumber, 1.second)
```

However, the purpose of future's is not to block on asynchronous work, as `Await` does, but instead to use the result of the future when becomes available.

The key to using `future` is understanding that it does not actually hold the value of your computation, but rather is promise that at some point in the future, it will provide that value.

The usual use case is a request coming into a server that requires some work, which may take some time and itself wait on IO, like this:

```
def receiveMsg(msg: String, caller: Caller) = {
   doSomeAsyncWork(msg).map(response => caller.send(response)
}
```

I.e. you are called with an object that has a `send` method that you want to call when `doSomeAsyncWork` is done, but you don't want to block the current thread until that `future` completes. Instead you `map` the `future`, which means that `response => caller.send(response)` will be called for you when `doSomeAsyncWork` is done.

Answer (score 0):

futureNumber is of type `Future[List[Int]]`, since you defined it as such in

```
val futureNumber = future {
  showNumbers.filter((a: Int) => a % 2 == 0)
}
```

Therefore, when you print futureNumber, that is what gets printed. The variable does not get reassigned to the future value! If you want to print the value of the future, you need to do it inside the onSucess callback:

```
futureNumber onSuccess {
 case resultList => println(resultList)
}
```

Alternatively, you can block waiting for the future with

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import duration._
val theList = scala.concurrent.Await.result(futureNumber, 10 seconds)
println(theList)
```

Although this might not work if done in the REPL.

The whole point of the `Future` type is that it acts as a marker that alerts you to the presence of concurrency and should help you handle it better.